# Can't login into API with angular getting error 400

Tags: angular, typescript, api, jwt

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to send POST request to an web API using http and jwt. I followed this tutorial , but I always get error 400 from the request.

https://bezkoder.com/angular-10-jwt-auth/

Using Postman i get status 201 and I think the problem is that in my angular project it doesnt get the 'token' from the api , even with interceptor..

[Postman login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBCGf.png)

Error from the login:

[Login error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziodZ.png)

How I can get this token into my app ?

**login.page.ts**

```
  async newLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      return this.authService.loginService(email, password).subscribe(async (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res['token']) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res['token']);
          console.log(res);
        }
      },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
    }
 catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      console.log(email, password);


      const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        keyboardClose: true,
        message: "Checking credentials ...",
        duration: 3500
      });
      (await loading).present();
      this.isLoading = true;
      setTimeout(async () => {
        (await loading).dismiss();
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.clicked = false;
      }, 2500);

      setTimeout(async () => {
        const error2 = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: 'Warning!',
          message: 'Login failed.' + err.message,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        await error2.present();
      }, 3000);


    }
}
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

  loginService(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${this._loginAPI}`, { email, password }, httpOptions)

  }
```

**auth-interceptor.ts**

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log("Interception In Progress"); //SECTION 1
    const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');

    req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
    req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
    req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });

    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          //401 UNAUTHORIZED - SECTION 2
          if (error && error.status === 401) {
            console.log("ERROR 401 UNAUTHORIZED")
          }
          const err = error.error.message || error.statusText;
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Why use axios when Angular has http client?

Comment: I tried both solutions , but didn't work.. Same error but no clue

Comment: And what can you see in browser's network when you send request? What difference with Postman?

Comment: Maybe, I think, I know what problem. `Hint:` take a closer look at the login information on image what you sent.

Comment: The difference is the token i guess , but when I connect from postman i have cookies or tokens , simple just it gives mes 201 and mine 400.

Comment: `{ email: { email: "..."` It is not duplication? or is it intentional? :)

Comment: This api is from my friend , but why it looks like that?

Comment: Was that the mistake? :)

Comment: I will tell him to change his backend propertiers to see if something changes. Thank you for help!!